# ¿Como coger valor de un input type hidden?

Tags: php, html, mysql, entrada

Tengo un atributo hidden donde almaceno los nombres que luego usare para borrar filas según el nombre escogido. Al principio si puedo usar esa variable sin problemas pero la segunda vez que la uso no funciona. Este es el error que me da: Notice: Undefined index: sdel in H:\XAMPP\htdocs\Prueba1\index.php on line 119

```html
//Lista de series
if(isset($_GET['lseries'])){   
//include("lseries.php");

$cnx=conectar();
echo "<br>";
$cseries="SELECT * FROM SERIES";
$res =  mysqli_query($cnx,$cseries) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<br>";
if($res){
echo "<table border=2px>";
echo "<tr><th>Nombre</th><th>Link</th><th>Nota</td><th>Eliminar</td></tr>";
while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
 echo "<tr><td>$fila[0]</td>";
 echo "<td>$fila[1]</td>";
 echo "<td>$fila[2]</td>";
 echo "<td>";
 echo "<form method='GET' action='index.php'>";
 echo "<input type='hidden' name='sdel' id='sdel' value='$fila[0]'>"; //Este es el valor que quiero coger
 echo "<input type='submit' name='delete' id='delete' value='Eliminar'>";
 echo "</form>";
 echo "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
  }
  
echo "</table>";
 }
mysqli_close( $cnx );




//Borrar registro
if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
 echo "<br><br>";
 $nombre=$_GET['sdel'];
 echo "<h1 class='warning'>¿Seguro que quieres borrar $nombre?</h1>"; //Aqui si he podido usar el valor de $nombre
 echo "<table>";
 echo "<form method='GET' action='lseries.php'>";
 echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='accept' id='accept' value='Aceptar'></td>";
 echo "<td><input type='submit' name='back' id='back' value='Volver'></td></tr>";
 echo "</form>"; 
}
 if(isset($_GET['accept'])){
  $nombre=$_GET['sdel']; // En esta linea salta el error
  $sql="DELETE FROM series WHERE Nombre='$nombre'"; //Aqui ya no coge el valor de $nombre
  $cnx=conectar();
  $deletes=mysqli_query($cnx,$sql);
  mysqli_close( $cnx );  
 }
 #echo $deletes;
```

Comment: ¿No será que la segunda vez habrás borrado el input `sdel`?  De todos modos no veo cuál es tu lógica / código de borrado. Y hasta intuyo que esto se puede hacer de otra manera.

Comment: Pues si, creo que era eso, pensaba que con usarlo una vez dentro de un formulario ya valía para todos pero veo que no. Lo que pretendía era tener una tabla y que justo a la derecha de cada fila, cada una tenga su formulario para borrarla según su nombre.Seguro que se puede hacer de muchas maneras pero no se me ocurria otra, gracias por contestar @A.Cedano

Comment: Si he entendido bien, querrías  tener una tabla con filas y en cada fila un botón que diga borrar o algo así y que al pulsar en ese botón se borre esa fila. Ese tipo de cosas se puede hacer muy fácilmente, pero desde Javascript... Es el lado correcto de hacerlo, no desde PHP.

Comment: Eso mismo, se también un poquito de Javascript pero nunca he hecho una pagina con Javascript y PHP juntos, no se como se podría poner.

Comment: Te voy a mostrar un ejemplo...

Answer (score 1):

Eso es por que ya no estás pasando el input hidden al segundo formulario, tienes un html que muestra fun formulario Ahí debes de poner de nuevo el campo hidden

```
if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
    echo "<br><br>";
    $nombre=$_GET['sdel'];
    echo "<h1 class='warning'>¿Seguro que quieres borrar $nombre?</h1>"; //Aqui si he podido usar el valor de $nombre
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<form method='GET' action='lseries.php'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$nombre."' name='sdel'>;  //aqui pones de nuevo el input hidden. De lo contrario no va a existir nunca en la siguiente peticion
    echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='accept' id='accept' value='Aceptar'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='back' id='back' value='Volver'></td></tr>";
    echo "</form>"; 
}
```

Tambien hay que decir que esa forma de imprimir html en PHP es pésima, trata de no usarla. Suerte.

Comment: Era eso, muchas gracias. Es que llevo muy poco tiempo aprendiendo php y empezaron a enseñarme asi, ¿por que es malo usar html dentro de los echos?

Comment: mas allá de malo, es que estás haciendo código espaguetti @Mnavarro mezclando lenguajes con distintos fines

Comment: Porque es una forma muy confusa y muy dificil de mantener, procura separar el html del php si necesitas colocar codigo php dentro de html usa algo como <input id="<?php echo $myVar ?>">, de esa forma es mejor, pero bueno ya lo aprenderás con el tiempo y más adelante usarás template engines. :)

Answer (score 1):

Este código Javascript hace lo que quieres.

Explico punto por punto:

1. En cada fila hemos puesto un diseño con una `x` dentro, usando la librería bulma, el código es este: `<a class="delete"></a>`. Ahí puedes poner otra cosa, lo importante es la forma en que se seleccionan esos elementos para *escuchar*  el click sobre ellos.
2. Dado que el elemento tiene una clase `delete`, podemos seleccionar todos los elementos con esa clase así: `var allDelete = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');`
3. Luego aplicamos un `forEach` a todos los elementos donde ponemos a cada uno un *listener*  que se lanzará cuando se haga click sobre el dibujo con la `x`.
4. La función del *listener* identifica cuál fue el `td` sobre el que se hizo click con: `event.target.parentNode`
5. Luego determina la fila a que pertenece este `td` con `parentNode`
6. Y finalmente le pide al papá de la fila que la borre con `removeChild`

Aquí tienes un ejemplo.

Lo que se hace con esta tabla, se puede hacer con cualquier otra.

```js
var allDelete = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');
allDelete.forEach(function(button, index) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var td = event.target.parentNode;
    var tr = td.parentNode;
    tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" integrity="sha256-2pUeJf+y0ltRPSbKOeJh09ipQFYxUdct5nTY6GAXswA=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<table class="table is-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><abbr title="Position">Pos</abbr></th>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Action</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Leicester City</td>
      <td>
        <a class="delete"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Real Madrid</td>
      <td>
        <a class="delete"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Manchester United</td>
      <td>
        <a class="delete"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Milán FC</td>
      <td>
        <a class="delete"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo @A.Cedeno, con tus explicaciones lo veo bastante claro. Lo pondré en practica en mi próximo ejercicio.