# Obtener valor de input de acuerdo a button pulsado en la misma fila

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente codigo en jquery u como veran creo una tabla con un edit para ingresar la cantidad de un articulo para añadir al carro de compras, entonces hay un boton en cada fila a su vez:

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
listar();




var nombreBusqueda;

 $("#nombre").keyup(function() {
            
        nombreBusqueda=$("#nombre").val();
        filtrar(nombreBusqueda);
    });
   $("#cod").keyup(function() {
       
        codBusqueda=$("#cod").val();
        filtrarcod(codBusqueda);
    });
  var id;
  var nombre;
  var marca;
  var producto;
    var precio;


$("#Agregar").click(function(event){
  var cantidad=$("#cant").val();
  
  if (cantidad!==""){
    var accion = "agregar";
    $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/procesoDetalle.php",
            data: {accion,id,cantidad,nombre,marca,precio}, 
  dataType:'html',
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
             alert('agre');      
                      
            }
        }).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

  if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

    alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

    alert('Requested page not found [404]');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');

  } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

    alert('Time out error.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

    alert('Ajax request aborted.');

  } else {

    alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

  }

});

    
  } else{
    alert("ingrese cantidad");
  }
});


});
function filtrarcod(dato){
        var filtrado=[];
        var existe;
    for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
 if (content[i].codalfa.toLowerCase().indexOf(dato.toLowerCase())!=-1) {
        filtrado.push(content[i]);
        
       
    }
}
     if (filtrado.length>0) {
        
            $("#resultadomodal tbody").empty();
        
            for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].codalfa + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].detalle + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].precio + "</td>" +
                          "<td>"+"<input type='text' value='1' class='form-control input-sm' id='cant'tabindex='3' id='"+filtrado[i].idproducto+"' placeholder='cant'/>" + "</td>" +
   
          
                     "<td>"+
" <a  class='btn btn-primary' onclick='agregarProducto("+filtrado[i].idproducto+");' name='agregar' >+</a></td>"+
          
                  
                    "</tr>";
                  
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultadomodal tbody");                 
       }
 
  
}};
function filtrar(dato){
        var filtrado=[];
        var existe;
    for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    if (content[i].nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(dato.toLowerCase())!=-1) {
        filtrado.push(content[i]);
        
       
    }
}
     if (filtrado.length>0) {
        
      $("#resultadomodal tbody").empty();
        
            for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].codalfa + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].detalle + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].precio + "</td>" +
                    "<td>"+"<input type='text'value='1' class='form-control input-sm' id='cant'tabindex='3' id='"+filtrado[i].idproducto+"' placeholder='cant'/>" + "</td>" +
   
          
                     "<td>"+
          " <a  class='btn btn-primary' onclick='agregarProducto("+filtrado[i].idproducto+");' name='agregar' >+</a></td>"+
          
                  
                    "</tr>";
                  
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultadomodal tbody");                 
       }
 
 
  
}};
function listar(){

    tipofiltro="todos";
  $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/filtroP.php",
            data: { "tf": tipofiltro}, 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
           content=data;
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].codalfa + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].detalle + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].precio + "</td>" +
                         "<td>"+"<input type='text' value='1' class='form-control input-sm-2' id='"+data[i].idproducto+"' name='cant' tabindex='3' placeholder='cant'/>" + "</td>" +
   
          
                     "<td>"+
           " <a  class='btn btn-primary' onclick='agregarProducto("+data[i].idproducto+");' name='agregar' >+</a></td>"+
         
                  
                    "</tr>";
                  
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultadomodal tbody");                 
       
    
               
            }



        }  
});
}
 function agregarProducto(idproducto){
    var cantidad=0;
    cantidad=$("input[id="+idproducto+"]").val();
    alert(cantidad);
    id=idproducto;
    nombre="mm";
    marca="mm";
    precio=2;
    alicuota=0;
  
         if (cantidad!==""){
    var accion = "agregar";
 
    $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/procesoDetalle.php",
            data: {"accion":accion,"id":id,"cantidad":cantidad,"nombre":nombre,"marca":marca,"precio":precio,"alicuota":alicuota}, 
         

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
           
        }).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

  if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

    alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

    alert('Requested page not found [404]');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');

  } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

    alert('Time out error.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

    alert('Ajax request aborted.');

  } else {

    alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

  }

});

    
  } else{
    alert("ingrese cantidad");
  }

}
```

El caso es que la preimera vez que entro toma bien el valor introducido 1 o 2 etc.

Pero si cierro el modal form y lo reabro e inserto el mismo articulo, el valor de cantidad es el idproducto y no el texto ingreado. Si intento agregar uno que no esta en la lista va todo bien y la verdad no encuentro explicacion.
En la imagen adjunta me explico: quiero tener un edit y un agregar por cada fila para que el user ponga cantidad y pulse el mas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No puedes usar el mismo `id` para todas las filas.

Comment: Pero cada fila va variando data[i].idproducto, osea no es el mismo id, de hecho si agrego el primero suma1 y el producto 28 suma 28. osea va variando

Comment: En tu codigo tienes dos atributos `id` el primero es `cant` y el segundo es el que mencionas.

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. [Justo ayer hice algo parecido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/233121/29967), aquí la idea era borrar la fila sobre la que se ha pulsado un botón, pero se puede aplicar la misma lógica para editar. Otra cosa que te recomendaría es no hacer actualizaciones del DOM dentro de los bucles, es mejor concatenar en una variable y actualizar una sola vez al salir del bucle. No es lo mismo actualizar el DOM `N` veces, que hacerlo una sola vez. Eso podría tener un impacto más o menos serio en el rendimiento en muchos casos.

Comment: ok ahora entiendo. Y como hago mediante un boton referirme al producto de la fila y a la cantidad que se metio en esa fila?

Comment: Ahi puse una imagen ilustrativa del formulario que tengo ahora y lo que deseo es al apretar el mas cargar en el carrito el producto con la cantidad ingresada.

Comment: Voy a tener q utilizar el selector de la fila de la tabla nomas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione usando otro atributo del edit, en lugar del id obtengo el "value" del edit cuyo name es el idproducto:

```html
        "<td>"+"<input type='text' name='"+data[i].idproducto+"' class='form-control input-sm-2' value='1' tabindex='3' placeholder='cant'/>" + "</td>" +
   
          
                     "<td>"+
           " <a  class='btn btn-primary' onclick='agregarProducto("+data[i].idproducto+");' name='agregar' >+</a></td>"+
```

Luego:

```html
cantidad=$("input[name="+idproducto+"]").val();
```

Muchas rgacias